# Does Liberty has limitation with heap size?

Tags: websphere-liberty

Is there any limitation of using Liberty over WAS? I have found mixed articles online some states there is a limitation for Heap size, is that true.

This Article[enter link description here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/websphere-application-server-everyone/) states that max memory for Liberty should not exceed 2 GB

There definitely many benefits. But is the max heap memory only 2GB allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2GB limit listed in that article is the "Freemium" heap limit. If you exceed that 2GB heap limit for your entire organization (business, non-profit, personal use, etc) then you would be required to pay for the usage as per IBM software purchase guidelines.

There is no technical heap limit for Liberty. We have deployments of Liberty that use 32 GB of heap, for example. If you have purchased entitlement for Liberty there is no heap limitation per server or per organization.